# Fluctuating time between realms?

Tags: physics, time

I'm going to try my best to describe what I'm looking for, but it's a bit hard to explain.

I'm imagining a world with multiple realms and time fluctuates between them according to some sinusoidal wave and I want to figure out how to track the flow of time.

As a simple case, let's assume there are just two realms: A and B. I don't know if a regular sine wave is the right approach or not, but say realm A's time is flowing according to $\sin(2\pi x/3)$ and realm B's is flowing according to $\sin(2\pi x/5)$. These two sync up every 15 days, meaning that if you spend 15 days in either realm, then 15 days will have passed in the other realm as well. But any other point along the way, sometimes realm A will be ahead of realm B, and sometimes it'll be behind.

So my question is: is it possible to setup such a system, in which if I know that it's day x  within the 15 day cycle in realm A, I can determine what day in the cycle it is in realm B? If so, what is the math behind it? And how could this be extended to more realms, each with a different sine wave?

In other words; Wanting to have a function that given a time past some epoch will give the phase angle in units of hours. Eg day 43.5 realm B is lagging realm A by 3 hours. On day 50.8 realm B is leading realm A by 10 hours.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you understand that if the time "speed" is following a sine curve, it probably means your realm is living an infinite looping cycle (sin(t) will become negative at one point)? Is it what you intended?

Comment: @Tortliena No, I meant that the speed of the flow of time increases and decreases according to a wave, not that time is flowing forward and backward, so sometimes it's moving faster than the other realm, and sometimes is moving slower, but both realms are always moving forward in time.

Comment: What would x be in the formula? How would you measure the A is ahead or behind B? Do you have two time dimensions, one for A and B and another one to compare it?

Comment: @tstrickler Then I believe your time speed is closer to d(t) = sin(ax) * b + c, "a" being the frequency it changes (eg. : 2π/5 or 2π/3), "b" the magnitude of how fast and slow it goes, "c" a constant which should be above "b", and "x" a realm-independent clock time. That way your time flow will always move forward as your derivative function will always be > 0.

Comment: This is kind of unclear. I did my best to calculate it, but you're not clearly stating what you mean.

Comment: *"Realm A's time is flowing according to $\sin(2\pi x/3)\,$:* Your confusion will most likely magically disappear once you think hard about what is $x$ in this equation. Specifically, in what way is $x$ anything other that a uniform and not fluctuating time dimension common to the two realms? P.S. $\sin(2\pi x/3)$ is bounded between −1 and +1. That's not a lot of time span. You probably want something like $t = x + 1 − \sin(2\pi x/3)$...

Comment: The terminology you are looking for is phase, phase angle.  Eg a large industrial plant that has many electrical motors will cause a phase delay of the current causing the current peak to lag voltage peak.

Comment: VTC - As written, and as per the current only answer - This is not a worldbuilding question, but a Maths question - as such, would be better asked in one of the Math-specific SEs.

Comment: @TheDemonLord This would get closed on Math.SE for being off-topic. On the other hand, knowing how time relates in a world is essential to create calendars later on. It's not because the question heavily relies on equations that it's not worldbuilding :).

Comment: @Tortliena - I see your point - but I disagree - if you remove all of the world elements from it, you still have enough of the question to address the askers original problem - which is fundamentally a set of equations or a graphed set - see the integration answer below.

Comment: This is a good example of why I've come to despise the Real World Question policy. This question may be asked *because* the OP is involved in a worldbuilding effort, but the question has nothing to do with worldbuilding. After reading the [Help Center at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I can't see why this question shouldn't have been asked there. Strip the worldbuilding out of it, and it's just a math problem like you'd find in a text book (find a function that relates the following two functions....)

Comment: @TheDemonLord So what you're telling is that if you remove all worldbuilding elements this is not anymore a worldbuilding question. Indeed, and that's in fact very common as worldbuilding relies on many real-world matters so you still have a question with everything removed. The actual issue to be solved is what is it about if you remove nothing?

Comment: @JBH It would have been closed on math.se since they would have thought that, because they are imagining a world, it's worldbuilding not pure math. In this case it's not only maths, having a time system which actually makes sense to what you want is even more important (see the querent's misunderstanding on what their formula means vs what they actually want).

Comment: @Tortliena - "A train leaves Station A travelling at X miles an hour, B Train leaves station B travelling at Y Mile an Hour - when do they meet" - Is that a world building question or is it a Maths question? Now, I could add some additional world-buildingy elements to the question, but at it's core it is a Mathematical problem. This question IMO is no different. Even your point about Calendars - building a Calendar is fundamentally a question of maths, not a question of world building.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Yet building calendars *is* a worldbuilding question :). If you want to talk about it more, I invite you to get into this [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145626/discussion-from-fluctuating-time-between-realms). We're deviating from comments's purpose and rules.

Comment: @Tortliena Per my comment, "Strip the worldbuilding out of it...." I can't find any worldbuilding here. All the OP is asking for is the ability to relate two mathematical functions. The application of those functions may be worldbuilding (expressing a relationship in time that doesn't exist in the Real World), but that's like claiming the easel used to hold the canvas is art by virtue of holding the canvas upon which the painter paints. No, it isn't. I haven't voted to close, but I'm sorely tempted to simply because IMO this abuses the Real World Question policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use integration.

[image]

I took your two values on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and graphed them out, adding +1 to make them easy to read. The y axis represents the speed of time, the x axis represents real time passed to an outside viewer.

I then integrated the values to calculate the total time spent (real time times rate of time movement), the area, with [integrator calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and took away -1 to make it easy to read.

This is a simple way to work out when the realms sync up. When the integrated values touch, the green and purple values, time has synced, when the red and blue values touch the realms are moving at the same speed. You can adjust the values as you wish by tweaking the equations.

## To find when the times converge, do a simple  calculation.

Take the difference in x coordinates (days) between a convergence point, for example, 0.938, and your chosen point, such as 2 days.

Then work out the average time speed between those two points. At 0.938 it's 1.924, and at 2, it's .134 for the first equation, and 1.588 for the second. Take the first speed value and divide by the second.

For time one, (2-0.938) * (1.924+.134)/2=1.092 for time two, (2-0.938) * (1.924+1.588)/2=1.864872. The second curve will be about a day ahead.

Comment: I see what you're saying. So using this information, how would I then go from day x in realm A = day y in realm B?

Comment: I showed how you do the maths. You'd need a different equation of course to get a notable time difference of days.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. It's really no different than how relativity based time dilation works.

Put a record player on a cart. Move that cart at a fixed speed. Have each world on opposing edges of the turntable. As long as the linear speed of the cart exceeds the linear speed of the edge of the turntable, You can measure "now" in each world based on their distance from an arbitrary starting point.

If the linear speed of the edge exceeds the linear speed of the cart, then you have time travel, but otherwise it's just time dilation.